# Adding multiple users to AD

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

This script was working just fine today while testing. I made a few changes and started getting an error. I then went back to the very original script I got from the internet and now even it does not work. The errors are:

```
Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "A constraint violation
occurred."
At C:\Scripts\CreateTest2.ps1:51 char:2
+     $LABUser.SetInfo()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI

Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "There is no such object on the
server."
At C:\Scripts\CreateTest2.ps1:55 char:2
+     $LABUser.psbase.invoke("setPassword", $Pwrd)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation

Exception calling "InvokeSet" with "2" argument(s): "The directory property
cannot be found in the cache"
At C:\Scripts\CreateTest2.ps1:56 char:2
+     $LABUser.psbase.invokeSet("AccountDisabled", $false)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation

Exception calling "CommitChanges" with "0" argument(s): "A constraint violation
occurred."
At C:\Scripts\CreateTest2.ps1:57 char:2
+     $LABUser.psbase.CommitChanges()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Here is the script. What am I doing wrong?

```
function Select-FileDialog {
  param(
    [string]$Title,
    [string]$Directory,
    [string]$Filter = "CSV  Files(*.csv)|*.csv"
  )

  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
  $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
  $objForm.InitialDirectory = $Directory
  $objForm.Filter = $Filter
  $objForm.Title = $Title
  $objForm.ShowHelp = $true

  $Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()

  if ($Show -eq "OK") {
    return $objForm.FileName
  } else {
    exit
  }
}

$FileName = Select-FileDialog -Title "Import an CSV file" -Directory "c:\"

$SelectOU = "OU=Test2,OU=Users,OU=Domain Controllers"
$domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetComputerDomain()
$DomainDN = (([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()).Domains | ? {$_.Name -eq $domain}).GetDirectoryEntry().distinguishedName
$final = "LDAP://$DomainDN"
$DomainPath = [ADSI]"$final"

$UserInformation = Import-Csv $FileName

$OUPath = "LDAP://$SelectOU,$DomainDN"
$UserPath = [ADSI]"$OUPath"

foreach ($User in $UserInformation) {
  $CN = $User.samAccountName
  $SN = $User.Surname
  $Given = $User.givenName
  $samAccountName = $User.samAccountName
  $Display = $User.DisplayName

  $LABUser = $UserPath.Create("User", "CN=$CN")
  Write-Host "Please Wait..."
  $LABUser.Put("samAccountName", $samAccountName)
  $LABUser.Put("sn", $SN)
  $LABUser.Put("givenName", $Given)
  $LABUser.Put("displayName", $Display)
  $LABUser.Put("userPrincipalName", "$samAccountName@$domain")
  $LABUser.SetInfo()

  $Pwrd = $User.Password

  $LABUser.psbase.invoke("setPassword", $Pwrd)
  $LABUser.psbase.invokeSet("AccountDisabled", $false)
  $LABUser.psbase.CommitChanges()
}
Write-Host "Script Completed"
```

Comment: Sorry for the messed up format

Comment: So, you're asking what, exactly? What troubleshooting have you done so far? Have you searched for what the error messages mean? (The idea is to at least perform some perfunctory troubleshooting on your own rather than doing a "code dump" and then expecting someone else to debug and fix it for you.)

Comment: Constraint violation, the first and most important error, means you're asking the directory to do something it doesn't want to. Duplicating a sAMAccountName, duplicating a userPrincipalName, duplicating a distinguishedName or relative distinguishedName and so on.

Comment: I have done my own troubleshooting. I went back to the original code that always worked and delete all users from AD but still get the error. I will try with a list of new names but it shouldn't be duplicating anything since I have removed all users.

Comment: So essentially, yes: You are asking others to troubleshoot, debug/fix/rewrite your code for you. I would suggest that you should post a minimal example (see http://sscce.org) that doesn't have any GUI cruft or non-essential code so that others can easily reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try Removing the Quotes from

1) LABUser assignment i.e. CN = $CN.

2) Remove the CN = from that line.

Try it one by one i hope you get your answer.

Comment: CN= is required in that context, the arguments for Create must contain the object class and a relative distinguished name. The underlying method (which is presented on iADSContainer via ADSI) is documented here and presented in simplified form via a DirectoryEntry object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705987(v=vs.85).aspx